# What is the definition for a phrase describing where something is?

Tags: meaning, phrases

I am doing a school writing task and I would like to know the name of that phrase

Comment: You should give examples instead of trying to describe grammar in your own words. The phrase _on the landing_ in the sentence _The book is on the landing_ is called a "locative phrase" because it deals with location.